# Can someone explain to me if this is a singleton object? (Android)

Tags: android, singleton

i'm still new with singletons. I'm trying to use the DRY methode, but i'm not sure if it's correct. Below you find the class Authorization which i use to create a OkHttpClient and Retrofit.Builder. I'm not sure if it's the right way:

```
public class Authorization {

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit authorize(Activity activity){

    final String token = SharedPreferencesMethods.getFromSharedPreferences(activity, activity.getString(R.string.token));
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public com.squareup.okhttp.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request newRequest =
                    chain.request().newBuilder()
                            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token).build();
            return chain.proceed(newRequest);
        }
    });

    if(retrofit == null){
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                //10.0.3.2 for localhost
                .baseUrl("http://teamh-spring.herokuapp.com")
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    return retrofit;
}
}
```

The return value of the method authorize is returning a retrofit object.
Is it a singleton?

Here i call the api

```
CirkelsessieAPI cirkelsessieAPI = Authorization.authorize(getActivity()).create(CirkelsessieAPI.class);             
Call<List<Cirkelsessie>> call = cirkelsessieAPI.getCirkelsessies();
// more code here
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not. **A singleton is a design pattern that restricts the instanciation of a class to one object**. I'm sure you can see why you can instantiate more than one Authorization object, and while the class "Authorization" restricts the instanciation of the class Retrofit to one object for its attribute, it can't in any way restricts someone else from instantiating another Retrofit object somewhere else.

Comment: Do you have any idea, how i can create one retrofit object and use it in different activities in my application. Instead of creating one everytime. Thank you,

Comment: If you don't have access to Retrofit source code to make it a singleton, then there is simply no way you can restrict the number of object this class can instantiate. But you could at least make your "Authorization" class a singleton and only interact with Retrofit from there. This won't be perfect though because another programmer who may not know you are doing this could modify your source code and use a Retrofit object in an unintended way...

Comment: Okay I understand what i'm doing wrong. Thank you for your help